# Hide email or website addresses unless authenticated

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm developing a job board website with ASP.Net MVC and want to block any email or website addresses from being visible to unregistered users.

So for example if an employer posts a job and includes something in the description like 'To apply send an email to myemail@email.com', I want it to display 'To apply send an email to *hidden link - please login or register*' or words to that effect. When they login the links then become available.

I'm still very much at the learner stage with ASP.Net MVC so I'm not really sure where to start with this. I'm not sure if this is the right thing to do or if there is an alternative approach.

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: What version of MVC are you using? There are multiple ways to go about this, but if you provide that, I can suggest some specific code :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a [regex search](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) to look for email addresses in the posting and replace that with the link you want for the unregistered users.

**[Updated]**

```
  public ActionResult ShowPosting()
    {
    var description = descriptionFromDB();

    if(!registeredUser)
    {
    model.Description = logicToReplaceTheEmailAddress(description);
    }
    else
    {
    model.Description= description;
    }

    return View(model);

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Bumble Bee. I guessed I needed to do something like that, my main problem is how to go about it.If the user fills the description field and I'm displaying it in the view with Html.DisplayTextFor(model => Model.Description), how do I scan that field for emails?

Answer (score 0):

only777,

you may be best served by creating an DisplayTemplate for email addresses and running your code thro those. here's an example of what i mean. Inside your view:

```
<%: Html.DisplayFor( m => m.Email, "ViewIfAuthenticatedTemplate" ) %>
```

and then under views/shared/DisplayTemplates, add an item called ViewIfAuthenticatedTemplate.ascx and add the following code to it:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<string>" %>

<% if(Request.IsAuthenticated) { %>
    <%: Model %>
<% } else {%>
    <%: Html.ActionLink("hidden link - please login or register", "MyAction", "MyController") %>
<% } %>
```

not sure if the syntax is 100% correct, but you get the gist..

**[edit]** - in fact, you could use this DisplayTemplate for ANY text that had to be hidden if not authenticated.

Comment: Thanks for this jim. This is definately an option for me. Ideally though I wanted to be able to pick up any email addresses entered into the description amongst all the other text, as apposed to having a dedicated email field.

Comment: only777 - ahh, that changes everything, i was thinking that the email property was a seperate field. i'll have a 2nd think. probably best done in your service class tho in that case